# Implementation for API using Application Context - Phalcon

Tags: php, phalcon

I am having a bit of difficulty understanding how I can implement an API in a separate directory using an `Application` type object instead of an `Micro`.

Currently when I try to implement:

```
$application->get('/api/robots', function () {

});
```

within my `index.php` inside public, where I create:

```
$application = new Application($di);    

echo $application->handle()->getContent();
```

It always treats them as `view controllers` and ask for a `controller`.  I tried following the docs for creating a simple `RESTful API` and I ended up creating a separate folder called `api` where the `micro index.php` (follows the exact layout of the api micro application in the tutorial) lives, but at the end of the day I keep getting the `ApiController not found`.

I am a bit stumped and any clarification/simplification would be very helpful!

Here is the tutorial: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tutorial-rest.html

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use`Phalcon\Mvc\Application` over `Phalcon\Mvc\Micro`, you can handle your routing the same way as you would normally.

```
$router = new Phalcon\Mvc\Router();

// route for a GET request (controller: ApiController, action: requestAction)
$router->addGet('/api/request/{id}', [
    'controller' => 1,
    'action'     => 2,
]);

// route for a DELETE request (controller: ApiController, action: removeAction)
$router->addDelete('/api/remove/{id}', [
    'controller' => 1,
    'action'     => 2,
]);

// this works the same for 
// $router->addPut(...) and $router->addPost(...)

// other normal route
$router->add('/([a-zA-Z\-]+)/([a-zA-Z\-]+)/:params', [
    'controller' => 1,
    'action'     => 2,
    'params'     => 3
]);
```